# Check if json contains string value

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to make it so I can check whether a string is in a json. The way I am doing it is putting the values of the json into an array, then seeing if it contains the value. The issue is that it checks it all one by one. This causes it to say the user isn't working the shift, when they are. Then on the next loop, it says they are working.

```
 private void CheckIfAlreadyWorking(String result) throws JSONException {
    //removed code to condense
    //result is a json of the days that the user is already working
    if (datematcher.find()) {
        String date = datematcher.group(1); //Date of the shift the user is already working
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        String[] yourshifts = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        boolean end = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                yourshifts[i] = obj.getString("date");
            if (yourshifts[i].contains(date)) {
                //Already working that day
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: You are already working this day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(end == false){
                AddShift();
                end = true;
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        //Error
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the exact issue.
The code looks fine to me.

What is the problem that you are facing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:
Take a `boolean isfound = false;`

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                yourshifts[i] = obj.getString("date");
            if (yourshifts[i].contains(date)) {
                isfound = true;
                break;

            }
        }
```

Now outside of loop:

```
if(isFound ==true)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: You are already working this day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
   AddShift();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the **break;** statement in your code right after the Toast you're making.

So in case if they are working on that thay, after making the toast the break statement will end the loop for you and will not traverse the remaining objects in your jsonArray

Like this:

```
if (yourshifts[i].contains(date)) {
    //Already working that day
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: You are already working this day", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
}
```